# Filtering datetime column in pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to subset a `datetime column` dynamically but still keep the `column` in the `dataframe` because the function would be used for a `UI` but for some reasons, I do not see the column after applying the function.

Here is the helper function to do it

```
def get_df(df, start, end, datetime_col, columns):
    df = df.loc[(df[datetime_col]>=start) & (df[datetime_col]<= end)][columns]
    return df
```

Here is how I applied the function

```
get_df(df, start=datetime(2020,3,1), end=default_end_date, datetime_col="time_iso8601", columns=["Berlin"]).head()


   Berlin
0   0
1   6
2   9
3   19
4   24
```

I would like the `datetime_col` to be included in the dataframe as it is originally

Comment: You need to include both in columns of .loc.  Try `df = df.loc[(df[datetime_col]>=start) & (df[datetime_col] <= end), columns+[datetime_col]]`

Comment: What do you mean by $ and +?

Comment: @Pythonista Yep.  Editted.  And '+' is adding two list together to get a list of columns in .loc

Comment: haha, I didnt see that. thank you so much! Silly me

Answer (score 1):

> This should work

```
def get_df(df, start, end, datetime_col, columns):
        df = df.loc[(df[datetime_col]>=start) & (df[datetime_col]<= end)][[columns,datetime_col]]
        return df
```